# MongoDB aggregation : $sum values of a key in a collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb collection full of documents like this :

```
{
    _id : xxxxxx
    category : 1,
    tech : [
        {key:"size",value:5},
        {key:"color",value:"red"}
        {key:"weight",value:27.4}
    ]
}
```

My question is : how can I do to aggregate (average, sum or whatever) each item with key = "size" in this collection?

thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

When you have documents that contain an array you use the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator in order to access the array elements.

```js
db.tech.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$tech" },
    { "$match": { "tech.key": "size" } },
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": null,
        "totalSize": { "$sum": "$tech.value" }
    }}
])
```

So once the array is "un-wound" you can then [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) on whatever you want to use as a key under the `_id` field, for all documents in the collection use `null`. Any of the [group aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-group/) can be applied.

The array elements in the "de-normalized" documents will be available through "dot notation" as shown above.

Also see the full list of [aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) in the manual.

Comment: I tried your solution but it did not worked. I think you did not notice that my tech subdocument is an array of objects, so tech.size or tech.color is not accessible directly.

Comment: @FredMériot Don't know how that was missed in typing. See the edit. You need to filter in this particular case. There is another way to do this with the $cond operator as well

Comment: @FredMériot did you miss the edit comment. What about this does not meet your needs?

Comment: No, I did not succeed to make it works. I still have the problem with the $tech.value in the group directive.

Comment: @FredMériot possibly more typing mistakes but I do not see the problem in general. The statement works perfectly fine for me. Check the edit again.